# LDAP with gitlab: Undefined method persisted

Tags: gitlab

I'm currently setting up a gitlab server using a LDAP backend.
When I try to login as a user present in the LDAP db, I get the following error:

"Could not authorize you from LDAP because: "Undefined method 'persisted?' for #"

Peeking into the source code (specifically app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb) the villain seems to be:

```
    @user = Gitlab::LDAP::User.find_or_create(oauth)
    @user.remember_me = true if @user.persisted?
```

It is totally correct for him to fail here because there is no method persisted? (neither in lib/gitlab/ldap/user.rb nor lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb). Changing the second line to

```
    @user.remember_me = false #true if @user.persisted?
```

doesn't work either since remember_me is an invalid function for ruby.
I really have no clue about ruby, let alone Ruby On Rails, so I stopped digging here.

Since I certainly am not the first person to try using LDAP auth in gitlab I consider this an error on my side. Since authentication seems to work (if I enter a false password for the user gitlab happily tells me so), I don't have any idea where to start looking.

I appreciate any help from you guys,

Best Richard

**Edit:** My gitlab.yml [is here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44d09d3889e46dbb831d).

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem myself. The database lookup yielded a nil object due to the user creation failing (whenever a ldap user logs in, gitlab uses the ldap data to fill its own database).

During creation of the user database entry the query got an invalid email entry resulting in a failed insert query. Unfortunately this was very hard to debug.

In case anyone should have this problem, try changing the following code in lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb:

```
begin
    user.save!
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    raise_error ("(OAuth) Error #{e.to_s}") # <-- add this line
    log.info "(OAuth) Email #{e.record.errors[:email]}. Username #{e.record.errors[:username]}"
    return nil, e.record.errors
end
```

This will - in case gitlab is not able to add your user - print the error message the database backend returned as the usual red error banner when trying to log in. Keep in mind to remove this line when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a patch (tested on Gitlab 7.1.0). This code sets the gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] as username when a ldap user is connecting for the first time :

in /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb (see INCLUDE START and STOP) :

```
      user = model.build_user(opts)
      user.skip_confirmation!

      # Services like twitter and github does not return email via oauth
      # In this case we generate temporary email and force user to fill it later
      if user.email.blank?
        user.generate_tmp_oauth_email
      elsif provider != "ldap"
        # Google oauth returns email but dont return nickname
        # So we use part of email as username for new user
        # For LDAP, username is already set to the user's
        # uid/userid/sAMAccountName.
        email_username = email.match(/^[^@]*/)[0]
        # Strip apostrophes since they are disallowed as part of username
        user.username = email_username.gsub("'", "")
      else
        # INCLUDE START
        # if LDAP config "ldap_uid" is set : we pick this attribute to set the username :
        if ldap_conf['uid'].present?
            user.username = auth.extra.raw_info.send(ldap_conf['uid'])[0]
        end
        # INCLUDE STOP
      end

      begin
        user.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was importing (copying file) fro old gitlab repositories to new one.
Gitlab wasn't able to create clean folder for the new user.

Solution:

- remove imported repositories
- create new, empty repository by first login with LDAP credentials
- read your PRIVATE-TOKEN
- start gitlab server on your repository ie. 'git daemon --verbose --export-all'
- import data from old gitlab using API:

  ```
  curl -X POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxffxxxyyxxxxzzz" http://testserver07.lq/api/v3/projects"?name=project01&import_url=git://localhost/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories-old/repos/project01.git"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your email address in Gitlab DB is correct:

```
# login to Gitlab DB (MySql)
mysql -u gitlab gitlabhq_production -p

# check user email address
select email from users where username like 'foo';
```

Then remove stored LDAP objects from Gitlab DB for the user:

```
# clear ldap data
update users set extern_uid = '' where username = 'foo';
```

On next login Gitlab write a new extern_uid.